# Share Point 2007 deploying template from different site to existing site with data?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I'm about to do SharePoint template export from site collection A (no data) into site collection B (already used in production), since the site collection A is currently what we want to standardize the look and feel along with its components (lists, view).

My question is, what does the impact on the data in site collection B will they still be OK or overwritten or cannot be displayed due to the new list column layout ?

Answer (score 1):

Site templates are used to create new sites and they can not be applied on existing site. same applies for list and document library templates as well. If you want to change the look and feel of a existing site. either user theming and new custom master page deployment. or use SharePoint designer to change the look and feel on a site which is already created

Comment: thanks for the reply man, what I want is the site design (custom list and view).

Comment: you have to apply those settings on new site manually or by using code but templates will not help you out